# proving drop-down facilities in ANTLR

Tags: java, dsl

In my current project, I am developing a Domain Specific Language. for instance, the syntax of this language will be following:

```
structs:

    TempStruct 
        tempValue : double; 
        unitOfMeasurement : String;        

abilities:
    sensors: 
        TemperatureSensor  
            attribute responseFormat : String; 
            generate  tempMeasurement : TempStruct; // forward reference of previously defined structs
```

In above code fragment, you can see that `TempStruct` is previously defined. My requirement is  that I want to facilitate DSL programmers a drop down list of previously defined structure. So, programmer can easily select one `structs` from drop down list.

I started working on ANTLR, but I am not sure that how this can be achieved in ANTLR.
Any idea about this ?  your pointers and suggestions about other tools   are welcomed for writing DSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to provide answer of my question. I have just received pointers from our collaborators. It may help others.

Tools to create DSLs and their associated development environments:

```
Xtext:
```

- oAW xText: A framework for textual {DSLs}
- http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/

  Spoofax:
- The Spoofax Language Workbench. Rules for Declarative Specification
  of Languages and IDEs
- http://strategoxt.org/view/Spoofax/

  Other references:
- http://martinfowler.com/articles/languageWorkbench.html
- http://www.languageworkbenches.net
- http://splashcon.org/2011/program/demonstrations (Cedalion, The
  language of languages, Testing Domain-Specific Languages,